# how is the type casting happening in the below example

Tags: solidity, contract-development

while reading the ethereum docs about contracts came across the example mentioned [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html). In the **ownedcontract** constructor there is a casting at statement#2

`creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);`

where msg.sender is of type address.

At first glance, I thought it's a constructor call but in the explanation it is clearly mentioned that it is a type cast.

How is it a cast? what is happening in the above statement?

1. To access a contract we need the address of the deployed contract
   right?
2. How is the contract available in the first place?
3. Will the contract be still available if they both are deployed
       seperately i.e, one after another?

Answer (score 3):

> To access a contract we need the address of the deployed contract right?

Right. However, in this example, the `OwnedToken` contract is actually created by an existing, already-deployed instance of a `TokenCreator` contract. See below where the `TokenCreator` contract calls `new OwnedToken(name)`. When a contract creates another contract, the creator contract is the `msg.sender` of the created contract. Since it wants to later be able to call methods on its creator contract - specifically `isTokenTransferOK()` - it stores its address in its constructor.

> How is the contract available in the first place?

See above: Somebody had already mined `TokenCreator`, which has a method that creates an instance of `OwnedToken`.

> Will the contract be still available if they both are deployed seperately i.e, one after another?

Well, you could have created an `OwnedToken` separately rather than making a method in `TokenCreator` that could create contracts. But `OwnedToken` needs to know the address of `TokenCreator` for when it needs to call `isTokenTransferOK()`. The way it's currently written that's done by relying on the fact that the relevant `TokenCreator` was its `msg.sender`. If you create the contract yourself then *your* address will be `msg.sender`, so that wouldn't work. You'd need to write it slightly differently - for example by adding an extra parameter to the constructor allowing you to pass in the address of the relevant `TokenCreator`. (You'd probably also rename `TokenCreator` to something like `TokenController`, since it wouldn't be creating tokens any more...)

Comment: after going through it again is it not some king of cyclic? I mean Owned contact is creating TokenCreator in the constructor and again TokenCreator is creating an instance of OwnedToken again?